# add class to background image

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, images, twitter-bootstrap, custom-background

I'm trying to make a wordpress theme, using as framework the twitter bootstrap. On one page template I need to use the featured image as a background image, so I used this code:

```
<?php
global $post;
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
?>
<div class="mainblogwrapper img-responsive img-center" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important; background-attachment : fixed;">
```

Everything looks great but I only have one problem. The image will not center for different screen sizes. (**I see the whole image on 1920X1080 screen, but only the left of it on mobile screen**).

I use the img-responsive and img-center classes but it is still not showing properly.

Check the website here http://aspalisvillas.com/

How can I make the background image to show properly? How to make it responsive?

Comment: You **can't** add a class to a background image. You *can* add a class to an element such as `<div>`, `<img>`, `<a>`, etc. So whatever you're adding the `$src` variable to, just add the class to that, otherwise try using CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please check my edited question, I have posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the style "background-position: center center;" and it work perfectly!

So the new code will look like this:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );
?>
<div class="mainblogwrapper" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important; background-attachment : fixed;background-position: center center;">
```